# How to display the time for this [h]:mm:ss format?

Tags: c#, wpf

we having the Time-Span value in the like below. And i want to display this time-span value with this [h]:mm:ss (same as Excel format) in c#.

**Codes**

```
var timeSpan = new TimeSpan(45, 15, 15);
```

I am expecting this time span will change based on the provided formats.

If I giving this Format h:mm:ss it will show the value as 21:15:15.

If I giving this Format [h]:mm:ss it will show the value as 45:15:15.

If I giving this Format @ it will show the value as 1,885590451.

If I giving this Format [mm]:ss,000 it will show the value as 2715:15,015.
I am expecting the below,

Time in Excel: 45:15:15,015

How can i achieve this in c#?

Thanks,
Sathiyathanam

Comment: Also `Code` is singular. In computer science, "code" is used as a mass noun, specifying the collection of instructions in a specific arrangement as a whole and in no specific quantity. Whether it's one line of code or ten pages, it is still referred to as code, not codes.

Comment: [Standard TimeSpan Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-timespan-format-strings), [Custom TimeSpan Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, you can't do it with a .NET format string (but you can [support a uservoice suggestion to add that feature](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/4050034-add-standard-formats-to-timespan-which-allow-the-f)). I have marked your question as a duplicate of another question which describes the workarounds currently available.

Answer (score 2):

There's no such format specifier. You could write an extension method which does this:

```
public static string FormatGreater24h(this TimeSpan span)
{
    return $"{(int) span.TotalHours}:{span.Minutes}:{span.Seconds}";
}
```